# Measuring the smoothness of a curve

Tags: python, machine-learning, curve

In deep learning, accuracy curves are crucial for evaluating a model's performance. Typically, an accuracy curve resembles a logarithmic function, although the reasons for this are beyond the scope of this question. Large spikes in the accuracy curve can indicate issues such as an inappropriate batch size. Let's examine these curves:

[image]

Here, I have plotted a function (log(x)) with different random noises of alpha, using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x, alpha):
    return np.log(x) + alpha * np.random.normal(size=x.size)

def main():
    x = np.linspace(0.5, 3)
    for i in [0, 0.1, 0.3]:
        plt.plot(x, f(x, alpha=i),label=fr'$\alpha$ = {i}')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My objective is to determine the smoothness of these curves in order to infer the original alpha value. The only thing that hints a solution to me, is the integral of squared second derivative; but I think there might be a better, more accurate solution.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: It sounds like you're describing instantaneous velocity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity) but accuracy itself IS the metric for evaluating the model's performance. You could calculate error or the inverse of accuracy, which should approach zero, and which is also a metric for a model's performance. I think what you're getting at is how to find the alpha (or learning rate factor) that best "fits" the model (i.e. the alpha value that results in the most optimal learning curve). Typically I write models where learning rate is default of 1.0, so that lowering or raising translates into a %.